# Keycloak Policy Enforcement with URI that maps to multiple resources

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-spring-boot-starter

I'm using Keycloak (21.0.0) to manage the authorization for my Spring Boot (2.7.10) application.
I have configured some resources that can only be accessed by certain users.
This works great!
Now I want to allow the admin to access all resources.

Here is an overview of my Keycloak configuration.

```
** Authorization - Settings **  
Decision strategy: Affirmative 

**Authorization - Resources**      
name: all comments
URIs: /api/comments/*
Authorization scopes: GET

name: first comment
URIs: /api/comments/1
Authorization scopes: GET

**Authorization - Scopes**  
name: GET

**Authorization - Policies**      
[role policy]
Name: admin
Roles: admin

[user policy]  
Name: fubar
Users: fubar

**Authorization - Permissions**  
[Scope based]  
Name: admin_can_read_all_comments
Resources: all comments
Authorization scopes: GET
Policies: admin

[Scope based]      
Name: fubar_can_read_first_comment
Resources: first comments
Authorization scopes: GET
Policies: fubar
```

When I evaluate Fubar in the Keycloak web client, the all_comments resource evaluates to DENY and the first_comment resource evaluates to PERMIT. When I evaluate admin in the Keycloak web client, the all_comments resource evaluates to PERMIT and the first_comment resource evaluates to DENY.

I would expect that both fubar and admin can GET /api/comments/1
But in reality the admin get's 403 when he tries to GET /api/comments/1
**Is this behavior expected?**

I'm guessing this behavior is related to the implementation of the keycloak-policy-enforcer. What will the policy enforcer do when a URI maps to multiple resources with a different outcome?

Here is my Spring Boot Config:

```
keycloak:
  securityConstraints:
    - authRoles:
        - "*"
  securityConstraints[0]:
    securityCollections[0]:
      patterns[0]: /*
  principal-attribute: preferred_username
  auth-server-url: http://kc-host:8080/auth
  realm: my-realm
  resource: my-authz-client
  bearer-only: true
  credentials:
    secret: s3cr3t
  policy-enforcer-config:
    http-method-as-scope: true
    lazy-load-paths: true
    enforcement-mode: enforcing
    path-cache-config:
      lifespan: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In Keycloak, evaluating a user's access to a resource typically involves the use of policies and permissions defined within Keycloak's Authorization Services.

You need to enable and configure Authorization Services in Keycloak.
This involves setting up policies, permissions, resources, and scopes.

`Resources` : The things you want to protect, such as APIs, web pages, or any other resource. It is target of API.

`Scopes`: It is action, like a read, write, delete to performed on the resource.

`Permission`: the association between resources and scopes. It decide allow or not to access a resource.

`Policy` :  Define the conditions under which access to a resource is granted.

So
The "fubar" user is assigned the "fubar" role.
The "admin" user is assigned the "admin" role.

The "fubar policy" has two roles, admin role and fubar role.
The "admin policy" has one role, admin role only.

The "fubar permission" has fubar policy and 1st comment resource.
The "admin permission" has admin policy and all comment resource.

Evaluate scenario 1,2,3,4 cases

Case 1 : admin user access all comment resource

Case 2 : admin user access 1st comment resource

Case 3 : admin user access all comment resource

Case 4 : admin user access 1st comment resource

###### Reason explain

See the following picture. (Why)

Case 1 : all comment resource has admin policy by all permission
admin policy has admin role, admin role has admin user.
so,  admin user can access all resource.

Case 2 : 1st comment resource has fubar policy by 1st permission
fubar policy has admin role, admin role has admin user.
so,  admin user can access 1st resource.

Case 3 : all comment resource has admin policy by all permission
admin policy has admin role, admin role has admin user.
so,  fubar user can't access all resource.

Case 4 : 1st comment resource has fubar policy by 1st permission
fubar policy has fubar role, fubar role has fubar user.
so,  fubar user can access 1st resource.

[image]

If the "admin" user is accessing both resources despite being assigned only the "admin" role

This `fubar_policy` can do it
assign role for both `my-client` admin & `my-client` fubar role

[image]

This `admin_policy` only assign role for `my-client` admin role

[image]

##### Client roles

[image]

##### Assign user for roles

[image]

[image]

##### Resource setup

[image]

##### Scope & Permission setup

[image]

##### Mapping policy and permission

[image]

##### Result

Admin permit both resources

[image]

fubar only permit for `first_comment`

[image]

##### Evaluate API

```
{Keycloak URL}/admin/realms/my-realm/clients/{cileint id}/authz/resource-server/policy/evaluate
```

[image]

Payload

```json
{
  "roleIds": [],
  "userId": "{user uuid}",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "first_comment",
      "owner": {
        "id": "{client id}",
        "name": "{client name}"
      },
      "ownerManagedAccess": false,
      "displayName": "{display resource name}",
      "attributes": {},
      "_id": "{resource id}",
      "uris": ["/api/comments/1"],
      "scopes": [
        {
          "id": "{scope id}",
          "name": "GET",
          "iconUri": ""
        }
      ],
      "icon_uri": ""
    }
  ],
  "entitlements": false,
  "context": { "attributes": {} }
}
```

[image]

Response Example

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "resource": {
                "name": "first_comment with scopes [GET]",
                "_id": "d8d416f3-c4eb-4157-a038-2828f279ae90"
            },
            "scopes": [
                {
                    "id": "97406598-494a-47c4-bcdb-ff763d18717a",
                    "name": "GET"
                }
            ],
            "policies": [
                {
                    "policy": {
                        "id": "33b2fe31-293f-4029-8e7d-25d4dd15f853",
                        "name": "fubar_can_read_first_comment",
                        "description": "",
                        "type": "scope",
                        "resources": [
                            "first_comment"
                        ],
                        "scopes": [
                            "GET"
                        ],
                        "logic": "POSITIVE",
                        "decisionStrategy": "AFFIRMATIVE",
                        "config": {}
                    },
                    "status": "PERMIT",
                    "associatedPolicies": [
                        {
                            "policy": {
                                "id": "90413ad9-6db7-49fa-889f-c408d3f6db63",
                                "name": "fubar_policy",
                                "description": "",
                                "type": "role",
                                "resources": [],
                                "scopes": [],
                                "logic": "POSITIVE",
                                "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
                                "config": {}
                            },
                            "status": "PERMIT",
                            "associatedPolicies": [],
                            "scopes": []
                        }
                    ],
                    "scopes": []
                }
            ],
            "status": "PERMIT",
            "allowedScopes": [
                {
                    "id": "97406598-494a-47c4-bcdb-ff763d18717a",
                    "name": "GET"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "entitlements": false,
    "status": "PERMIT",
    "rpt": {
        "exp": 1710303168,
        "iat": 1710302868,
        "jti": "5c9dd6b4-2adc-42e4-bf91-00268a25a369",
        "aud": "my-client",
        "sub": "fe955869-c533-4433-b947-e9d91f00217a",
        "typ": "Bearer",
        "azp": "my-client",
        "session_state": "31e60b44-3c4b-4b6c-b06c-c8d215040ec3",
        "acr": "1",
        "allowed-origins": [
            "http://localhost:8180/api/*"
        ],
        "realm_access": {
            "roles": [
                "offline_access",
                "uma_authorization",
                "default-roles-my-realm"
            ]
        },
        "resource_access": {
            "my-client": {
                "roles": [
                    "fubar"
                ]
            },
            "account": {
                "roles": [
                    "manage-account",
                    "manage-account-links",
                    "view-profile"
                ]
            }
        },
        "authorization": {
            "permissions": [
                {
                    "scopes": [
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "rsid": "d8d416f3-c4eb-4157-a038-2828f279ae90",
                    "rsname": "first_comment"
                }
            ]
        },
        "scope": "email profile",
        "sid": "31e60b44-3c4b-4b6c-b06c-c8d215040ec3",
        "email_verified": true,
        "preferred_username": "fubar",
        "email": "fubar@test.com"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for your detailed input. However, it doesn't really answer my question whether this behavior is expected. Can you explain why adding admin to the fubar_policy resolves the issue? It feels rather magical to me. The difference I spot is that now all resources evaluate to PERMIT for admin. But for fubar, we still have one resource evaluating to DENY (all_comments) and one to PERMIT (first_comment)

Comment: I added overview picture and explain why, I hope to address your question.

Comment: I do understand how keycloak resolves the resources, what I don't understand is what the keycloak-policy-enforcer does with this information. In my question, one URI maps to 2 resources, of which one resolves to PERMIT and the other resolves to DENY. How will the policy enforcer decide whether to grant access to this URI.

Comment: Be careful look my pictures, specially first picture (overview) and Resource setup. In the `fubar policy` has two roles(admin, fubar). And In the permission of Decision strategy is "Affirmative". It means at least one permission must evaluate to a positive decision in order grant access to a resource and its scopes. It means user admin OR fubar role, he can access fubar resource. It mapped `/api/comment/1` URIs.

Comment: Generally one resource map to multiple URIs. But if make multiple resources and each resource map to same URI. Your required feature is possible.